# how to create a pop up view in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I am trying to create a pop up view within an existing view: Whenever a button is pushed, the pop up view comes up

this is the code I've used to when the button is pressed

```
@IBAction func addFees(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
    view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 261)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

this is the code I use to  make it go away

```
@IBAction func doneButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
    listingfees.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1000, 320, 261)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

The problem is that I have other buttons and labels and they seem to overlap when the view comes up.
I don't know how to fix it. I am not sure if there is an easier away but I've been stuck on this problem for a while.

I want it to look something like the picture on the right

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Popover should be presented from base view controller if you want it to be on top

```
@IBAction func addFees(sender: UIButton){
let viewController =  "Your Popover View Controller class"
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 261)

let popoverPresentationViewController = viewController.popoverPresentationController
popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self
popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
presentViewController(playerInformationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Comment: When I push the button the screen goes black

Comment: Have u created a different class for popover?

Comment: I would suggest against hardcoding frame values - better to to do some light calculations to get the size ration you want regardless of screen size.